# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting while executing shell script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess

I am exuecuting shell script from my Python script -

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('#!/bin/bash\n\nulimit -n 8092\n\nulimit -a\n', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, executable='/bin/bash')
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
if proc.returncode != 0:
    print "Hello, ABC! " % stderr;
    sleep(0.05) # delay for 50 ms
else:
    print "Hello, FGH! " % stdout;
```

But it is always giving me error message as -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_python_1.sh", line 8, in <module>
    print "Hello, FGH! " % stdout;
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: do you mean  `print ("Hello, FGH! ", stdout)` or  `print ("Hello, FGH! %s" %  stdout)`? stdout is already a string though so just use the first

Comment: You need a `%s` in your format strings, such as `print "Hello, ABC! stderr=%s" % stderr`

Comment: Don't put a space before the end quote if you're using print with commas, because it automatically adds spaces. Also, this is Python 2.x, so don't put parens around the arguments to `print` unless you want to print a tuple (with parens, commas, quotes, backslash escapes, etc.). So `print "Hello, FGH!", stdout`. But otherwise, @PadraicCunningham is right, that's the simplest solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is misusing the [string formatting operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

The idea behind `my_string % my_values` is that Python goes through `my_string` looking for *format specifiers*, starting with a `%` character, and replacing them with the values from `my_values`. So, when you do this:

```
"Hello, FGH! %s" % stdout
```

… the `%s` will be replaced with the value of `stdout`. And similarly, if you do this:

```
"Hello, ABC! %s\nHello, FGH! %n" % (stderr, stdout)
```

… the first `%s` will be replaced with `stderr` and the second one with `stdout`. But when you do this:

```
"Hello, FGH " % stdout
```

… there *is* no `%s`, or any other format specifier, to be replaced by `stdout`. That's why it's complaining "not all arguments converted during string formatting": you have one argument, `stdout`, but zero of your arguments were "converted" by format specifiers, so there's one left over.

So, if you want the value of `stdout` to appear after the space, you need to put a `%s` after the space:

```
"Hello, FGH %s" % stdout
```

---

However, as Padraic Cunningham points out, you don't even really need that here. You're using a [`print` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement), and `print` can take multiple arguments and print them out with spaces between. So, all you need is:

```
print "Hello, FGH", stdout
```

(If/when you later go to Python 3.x, you will need to add parentheses around the arguments, because `print` is a normal function instead of a special kind of statement. But otherwise, this still works.)